# One pure Nash equilibrium, no mixed equilibrium?

Tags: game-theory

I'm given a 4x4 payoff matrix

\begin{bmatrix}(0,7)&(2,5)&(7,0)&(0,1)\\(5,2)&(3,3)&(5,2)&(0,1)\\(7,0)&(2,5)&(0,7)&(0,1)\\(0,0)&(0,-2)&(0,0)&(10,-1)\end{bmatrix}

There isn't any strategy that is dominated for both players.
As a combination of best responses, I see that (3,3) is a pure strategy Nash equilibrium. I tried to compute mixed strategy Nash equilibrium by setting probabilities of row player's actions as p,q,r,s and equating the payoffs for the column player, which yields p= -1/3

Does this mean there is no mixed strategy Nash equilibrium? Thus only one Nash equilibrium exists?

Comment: It only means that there is no equilibrium in which the row player plays each strategy with a positive probability.

Comment: So if I limit the strategies, there can be mixed equilibriums? But then how do I know which strategy to discard?

Comment: In principle, you have to do work through every subset of strategies for each player. But here the problem is a bit simpler. The fourth strategy of the column player, for example, is strictly dominated by a mixed strategy.

Comment: Oh I understand now. So to reduce a strategy, I need to find distributions of other strategies that dominate it right?

Comment: If that is possible, the strategy will certainly never be played with positive probability. So you can discard the strategy when looking for Nash equilibria.

Comment: So I'm left with (1,2,3) rows x (1,2,3) columns. But if I assign again p, q, r to the rows, q is given a negative number. I don't think the matrix can be reduced anymore since no combination of 2 strategies dominates the other. Is it safe then to assume there is no mixed equilibrium?